# How to (set permissions to) access a Google Storage bucket from a command line program?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, tensorboard

In my particular case, I would like to open an object with `Tensorboard` (A `Tensorflow` component). The command line instruction is the following:

```
# tensorboard --logdir=gs://mybucket/myobject
```

`gs://mybucket/myobject` is not a public object. So the line above generates a forbidden access error. The closest thing I found is `gsutil signurl` but it generates an http download link. What I think I need is an authenticated `gs://...` link, how can I create it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe that Tensorboard uses Application Default Credentials for auth. If you have the `gcloud` command installed, try running `gcloud auth application-default login` before running tensorboard, and I believe that it should use your credentials to fetch the GCS object.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!
gcloud auth application-default login && tensorboard --logdir $my_output_dir